# How to get subnet_id of ec2 instances in AWS using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Suppose we have some `ec2` instances in AWS. How can we get `subnet_ids` of these ec2s via `Terraform`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a data source to fetch the existing EC2 instance and then just reference the data source and the attribute `subnet_id` where needed. Check the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance#subnet_id

Comment: Please note that there is not only one instance. This method might be valid for an ec2 but I do not think it works for multiple instances.

Comment: @Andromeda Use a combination of filter and for_each to loop as necessary.

Comment: @Andromeda, how about this combination. Retrieve the instance IDs first with data "aws_instances" and then use the following:

data "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
  for_each = data. aws_instances.ids
  instance_id = each.value
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the data related `ec2` instances you want to get subnets of:

```
data "aws_instances" "ec2s" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["value"]
  }
}
```

2. Get `instance_id` of each `ec2` using count:

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2_subnets" {
  count    = length(data.aws_instances.ec2s.ids)
  instance_id = data.aws_instances.ec2s.ids[count.index]
}
```

3. Now, subnets could be referred:

```
resource "aws_***" "***" {
  count           = length(data.aws_instance.ec2_subnets)
  subnet_id       = data.aws_instance.ec2_subnets[count.index].subnet_id
  ###
  # Other Terraform attributes
  ###
}
```